# swipeleft and swiperight call id from html and link to href, turn pages in digital book

Tags: javascript, touch, swipe

first, sorry for the noobie question. but i have a digital textbook that works as a website, with each page in the book as a page in the website.

i have left and right page turns declared in my header as links (for example, if i'm on page 2, left is page 1 and right is page 3):

```
<a id="turn-the-page-L" href="../Text/A0.01.01.xhtml"></a>
<a id="turn-the-page-R" href="../Text/A0.01.03.xhtml"></a>
```

for those, i have click-able page turn icons set on the left and right that follow the link via:

```
onclick="window.open(document.getElementById('turn-the-page-L').href, '_self')"
```

i also have a small arrowkey script that performs the same function via left/right arrow clicks:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
   var key = e.which||e.keyCode;
   switch(key){
      //left arrow
      case 37:
         document.getElementById("turn-the-page-L").click();
      break;
      //right arrow
      case 39:
         document.getElementById("turn-the-page-R").click();
      break;
   }
});
```

NOW, i would ALSO like to set up a similar script for swipeleft/swiperight for mobile touch devices.

i've never worked with code for touch devices, and i haven't been able to figure this one out (though i imagine it is pretty simple).

can anyone help?!?

Comment: So, from my own experience, adding gesture support to web apps is a bit more of an mid-to-advanced level topic, which is why you're not likely to get an answer of "here's some code that will let you do it." Typically you need to bind to the `touchstart`, `touchend`, and `touchmove` events of the body and track the touch through it's lifespan, and decide what to do with it. There are libraries/plugins out there that aim to make it easier for you. A brief search yielded https://zingchart.github.io/zingtouch/ as a possible result. Hope that helps.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBSY7BOYRo4&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIBmqosTU2eg82bqSrT3WMt1&index=16 has a an implementation if you wanted to get an idea how to roll your own by example.

Comment: Oh wow ok great thanks for the starting points!